# In mathematical induction, does assuming $P(n)$ also assume all $P(k), 0 \leq k < n$?

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I am writing a proof by mathematical induction.

I prove the base case: $n = 0$. In the inductive step I want to prove $P(n + 1)$ by assuming $P(n)$. As it turns out, to show $P(n+1)$ I need to rely on  all $P(k), 0 \leq k \leq n$.

Is this possible? Or do I need to reconsider my proof strategy?

Comment: yes,that's right.and notice that it's possible to have a base case which is not zero,actually the base case in the minimal element of the set which is going to be inducted, also you are using strong induction ,there exist another version named "weak induction" or "induction", indeed they are equivallent.

Comment: That is called “complete/strong induction,” see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_(strong)_induction

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know strong induction was a thing. :)